# Octave xlwrite error

Tags: undefined, octave

I've recently installed Octave and after having a play around with it (I'm quite familiar with MATLAB) I wanted to export some data so installed the IO package.

However, now when I run the xlswrite function I get this error:

```
error: 'parse_sp_range' undefined near line 197 column 36
```

and I'm not entirely sure why as I've checked for the file and it is indeed in the folder that was installed. I'm running Octave 4.0.0 on Windows 7.

Cheers

Comment: how did you install octave's io package? Did you use `pkg install` and then `pkg load`?

Answer (score 1):

Just realised I'm a complete idiot. I still had the naked xlswrite.m file on my Desktop (which is the workspace) and as such it was trying to run that rather than the file found in the IO package.